# Access to IP camera in DVR via C++

Tags: c++, video, stream

I want to access the DVR with 4 IP cameras from my C++ program. For example, I want to get access to video stream of the first camera. Can it be done by means of OpenCV? What is the easiest way? Thank's.

Comment: "DVR" is just a Digital Video Recorder. AFAICT it could be a box with a power cord,  4 video inputs (over IP), and a DVD burner. You'd watch the video by playing back the DVD it burns.

Comment: did you find your answer ? I want to access to a similar DVR and I don't know how to begin